# Running Multiple Integration Tests Created At Runtime From XML Files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit.net

I've found this question, albeit dated: [xunit programmatically add new tests/"[Facts]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062975/xunit-programmatically-add-new-tests-facts/15163486)

I'm porting a python integration test library to c#. It's basically a console app which runs tests defined in XML files. Appx 160 separate files and about 200 tests in total.

I'd rather not write 200 separate test methods and run the tests from the XML files in a similar way to the python library, but using a testing framework like xunit.net

Aside from writing another console app, is it possible to add tests at runtime or is there a testing framework that allows this type of test creation?

Comment: xunit is used for unit testing (testing function scopes), not integration testing.  a unit test tests against conditional logic, calls and returns in the scope of a function that are in the code base.  One would mock responses and data returned from calls to other functions to reflect on conditional control flows.  Hence, unit tests won't ever provide coverage on workflows/scenarios - that is what integration testing is.  Ideally, unit testing occurs in your IDE while you code, it does not rely on your program running.

Comment: I should better qualify that 'won't ever' statement I made (I meant to edit the comment itself, but 5 mins passed).  I mean, unit testing won't cover interfacing nor functionality to even common libraries or technologies (like ADO.NET, or data stores.. in memory or persisted, nor System.IO) and their types.  In unit testing, you provide a mock/stub implementation to those interfaces/types that aren't themselves being unit tested.   I think, there's more here to consider in this refactor/migration effort before asking for recommendations on integration test frameworks (which may be off-topic).

Comment: @BrettCaswell Mocking the dB and api is actually quite easy. https://fullstackmark.com/post/20/painless-integration-testing-with-aspnet-core-web-api I've got that part up and running. I suppose my question still stands if I can create tests at runtime by loading from the xml files.